# Can't get these strings to add in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to add these strings below, but I keep getting an error. I have tried a bunch of things and they work in other files with different settings, but I can't get it work here and I am not sure why. The issues is around the string "healthy_kibble". I want that to be the sum of "kibble" + 100. But everything I tried seems to give me different errors. Here are two examples

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

def pickles_puppy(kibble, chicken):
    print(f"Pickles likes eating {kibble} pieces of kibble and {chicken} pieces of chicken")

kibble = input("how many pieces of kibble does Pickles want?")
chicken = input("and what about chicken?")
infinity = 1000000

pickles_puppy(kibble, chicken)

f = open(filename, 'w')
f.truncate()        

healthy_kibble =  (kibble + 1 + 100)

f.write(f'''Pickles is a little nugget \n
if it was up to her shie would only eat {infinity} pieces of chicken \n
But she has to be healthy \n
So she also has to eat her {healthy_kibble} pieces of kibble''' )
f.close()
```

Comment: `healthy_kibble =  (int(kibble) + 1 + 100)`

Comment: What errors do you get? And which line causes them?

Comment: Note that `1` is an integer value. You cannot add a string to an integer. You must convert the string to its numerical value first.

Comment: you can change here also `kibble = int(input("how many pieces of kibble does Pickles want?"))`  and NOTE:  F prefix won't work in python 3.x

Comment: if you're still wondering ...`input` gives you always `str` type back. You'll have to convert it how the other comments already showed.

Answer (score 0):

```
kibble = int(input("how many pieces of kibble does Pickles want?"))
```

Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this after your kibble input before trying to operate on it, you will get an idea what is wrong.

```
print(type(kibble))
```

I just ran that statement and got:

```
<class 'str'>
```

As Pradam observed, if you convert the input from string to int, you will be better able to add the values as integers.

Of course, there is always the obtuse answer,  if you enter,

```
healthy_kibble =  (kibble + '1' + '100')
```

you will get the not very useful answer of

```
331100
```